nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enabled
I'm getting this error when I run the helm command
Error: template: smartdoc-global/templates/uiservices-deployment.yaml:60:12: 
executing "smartdoc-global/templates/uiservices-deployment.yaml" 
at <include "app.geneosContainer" .>: error calling include: template: smartdoc-global/templates/_helpers.tpl:85:14: executing "app.geneosContainer" 
at <.Values.geneos.enabled>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enabled

i included geneos.enabled values in my values.yaml file
geneos:
  enabled: true
  image:
    registry: 
    namespace: 
    name: 
    tag:

I need to pass those values through helm command via deployment.yaml
  {{- include "app.geneosContainer" . | nindent 8 }}
volumes:
  {{- include "app.geneosVolume" . | nindent 8 }}


If the question is about JavaScript fix the tag.

Java and Javascript are completely different languages. This looks like Javascript

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that it is important to ensure you use the right tags in your question. Tags help to bring your attention to those readers who have knowledge of the subject. You originally had tags like "java", "reactjs" and "helper" and this has confused people who were experts in those subjects but had no idea what your question was about.

Even though you've defined it in values.yaml, it might not be passed correctly, or the template logic does not account for missing values.

There are a couple of details missing from this question.  It looks like you have a call {{ if .Values.geneos.enabled }} somewhere; what code includes that?  In the top-level deployment fragment you show, is there surrounding context like a range loop or with block that might rebind the . special variable?  Can you [edit] the question to include these details?
